# Solving $\sin(\frac{2\pi x}{a}) = 0$ on the interval $[-\frac{3a}{2}, +\frac{3a}{2}]$

Tags: trigonometry

I have the equation $$\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{a}\right) = 0$$
and I have to solve for $x$ in the interval $\left[-\frac{3a}{2}, +\frac{3a}{2}\right]$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: In general, $\sin(t) = 0 \iff \pi|t.$  Therefore, $(2x/a)$ must be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$\sin \theta = 0$ for $\theta = n\pi, n\in \Bbb Z$.

So, $$\frac{2\pi x}{a} = n\pi \Rightarrow x = \frac{an}{2}$$

Now select $n\in \Bbb Z$ such that $x$ (one or more) lies in the required interval.

Comment: really helpful, thanks

Comment: You're welcome!